# How to add layers to the bottom of a pretrained model in keras' functional api?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am running into an error while adding layers to the bottom of the pretrained VGG16 model from keras' functional api.

I was going through the Deep Learning for Python tutorials and I think the book was written in an earlier addition of keras where the Sequential API is being used instead.

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.layers import Input,Flatten,Dense
from keras.models import Model

inp=(150,225,3)
inputs = Input(shape=inp)
base = VGG16(weights='../input/keras-pretrained- 
models/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5',
         include_top=False,
         input_shape=inp)

base_output = base(inputs)
out = Flatten()(base_output)
out =Dense(256, activation='relu')(out)
out =Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(out)


model = Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=out)
```

I am see the following error. 
***AttributeError: 'InputLayer' object has no attribute 'outbound_nodes'***

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my imports

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input,Flatten,Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
```